# Symfony2 Filesystem - Save a stream of data in an existent directory

Tags: php, symfony, filesystems

I have a data stream that I need to save in a `PDF` file and then store that file in an already existent directory, which is `Documents/pdf`. This directory is at the same level of `src`, `app`, `web` directories, and has all the permissions to write in it.

With my solution I always have the file saved under the `web` directory. I want the file to be under `Documents/pdf`. This is my controller:

```
    /**
    * @Route("/api/savePdf", name = "save_pdf")
    * @Method("POST")
    **/
    public function savePdfAction(Request $request) {

        $pdfPath = $this->get("kernel")->getRootDir() . '/../Documents/pdf/';
        $data = $request->getContent();
        $name = 'file.pdf';
        $dateNow = new \DateTime('now');
        $date = $dateNow->format('Y-m-d H-i-s');
        $fileName = $date.$name;

        try {
            $fs = new Filesystem();
            $fs->dumpFile($fileName, $data);
            move_uploaded_file($fileName, $pdfPath.$fileName);
            return new Response ("File saved correctly", 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json') );
        }

        catch(IOException $e) {
            return new Response ("Error!", 500, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
        }

        return new Response();
     }
```

Comment: no error? only stored in the wrong path? try to `die(var_dump($this->get("kernel")->getRootDir()));`

Comment: @Matteo Yes, no error. This is the result -> string(30) "/home/user/AppBundle/app"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use

```
move_uploaded_file
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

> This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism).

I'm just guessing here but since you dump the content to a file yourself i don't think it does satisfy the move_uploaded_file usage condition.

Why don't you dump the content directly into the targetfolder and get rid of a manual move?

```
$fs->dumpFile($pdfPath.$fileName, $data);
```

should do the trick since your path is absolute anyways.